# Couldn't access using PSExec - PSTools

Tags: command-prompt, psexec

PSTools I downloaded and installed in C: \ PSTools. Then I did the following:

1 - I opened the Command Prompt

2 - C: \ PSTools> I did this: C: \ PSTools> `psexec`

3 - Then I did: C: \ PSTools> `psexec \ \ IP-u user calc`

But it returns this message:

```
C:\PSTools>psexec \\IP -u USER calc

PsExec v1.98 - Execute processes remotely
Copyright (C) 2001-2010 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

Password:
Couldn't access IP:
The network path was not found.

Make sure that the default admin$ share is enabled on IP.
```

Can you help me??
Thanks,

Comment: Did you actually enter an IP address or did you use the letters `IP`

Comment: I can not believe you're serious. You did really asked that question?
Of course I'm entering the IP address in this format for the example: 10.0.0.x

Answer (score 2):

My computer > Right click on "C:\Windows" > Share > Advanced Sharing > Check the box > Share name "admin$" > Permissions > Check all boxes for "Everyone"

Answer (score 2):

1.exzip the pstools  anywhere， such as  d:\pstools\

2.use cdm , and switch to d:\pstools

3.type

```
 psexec -u Administrator -p password \\192.168.1.111 netstat -na
```

to test it!

it will show the message of  192.168.1.111.

if show error message:

Error initializing crypto: object is already exist.

then you must：

2-1.use cmd with Administartor's Power.

or

2-2.use cmd , and tyep "run as ..." to pop out a administrator cmd, and use it.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest calling the start this way.

```
C:\pstools\psexec.exe
```

The second part
\10.0.0.x -u [i dont know what you looking for here]

Answer (score 0):

First try pinging the machine so you know you have access over the net.
Then try turning the fire wall off.
If this works you know you have a valid path between the machines. Then you have to figure out how to run it with the fire wall still on.